# Better way to do a countdown function in clojure?

Tags: clojure

While making a more complex function I wanted to do something like the below code. However it seemed a bit too complex for a simple countdown. Especially needing to use times in both the function and the loop. Is there a better/simpler way to do this? Answers/advice appreciated.

```
(defn the-final-countdown
  [times]
  (loop [times times]
    (if (> times 0)
      (do (print times) (recur (dec times)))
      (print times))))

(the-final-countdown 7);;OUTPUT -> 76543210
```

Reduce does not work in this case as far as I know because the function accepts a value and not a list.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It's not clear from the example. What is the purpose of counting down? Do you want to pause between each number printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```
user=> (defn countdown [n] (dotimes [x n] (println (- n x))))
#'user/countdown
user=> (countdown 7)
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
nil
```

Comment: AHHHHH there is a dotimes function. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It's nearly always a good idea to write pure functions instead of using side effects.

What you're doing here is going through all nonnegative integers less than or equal to `times` (in reverse order) and printing each of those integers. A simpler way to do that would be to use the built-in `range` function to generate the sequence of those integers, then concatenate all the elements of that sequence into a single string using `str`:

```
(defn the-final-countdown [times]
  (apply str (range times -1 -1)))
```

Example:

```
(the-final-countdown 7)
;=> "76543210"
```

If you really need to print something to the console, you can simply call `the-final-countdown` and then print the result:

```
(print (the-final-countdown 7))
;   76543210
;=> nil
```

If you'd like, you could also avoid those ugly `-1`'s in the function definition by generating an increasing sequence and calling `reverse` on it:

```
(defn the-final-countdown [times]
  (apply str (reverse (range (inc times)))))
```

Note that `reverse` needs to realize the entire lazy sequence returned by `range` in order to do its work, but since we're converting to a string anyway, this doesn't really matter.

If you're going to be printing a *very* long list of numbers, though, holding the entire sequence in memory may not be feasible. In that case, it may be necessary to use side effects in your function, which you can achieve using `run!`:

```
(defn the-final-countdown [times]
  (run! print (range times -1 -1)))
```

Comment: This is correct and helpful, and unfortunately not exactly what I was looking for. I am merely using the question as an example for a more complex application. I am looking to do something a given set of times while having access to the variable containing the current time.